# How do you create and use an indirectCommandBuffer in Swift for Metal GPU computations?

Tags: swift, metal

I am currently working on a project that uses the GPU to do computations on large datasets. Currently I'm investigating the potential of using indirectCommandBuffers to potentially speed up our code, especially since I'm are having trouble with its speed on the M1 processor (interestingly enough, the speed at which our program runs is super fast on AMD Metal GPUs). Another reason why I want to do this is to avoid having to create the exact same Compute Command Encoders 500+ times.

However, I'm having troubles with coding the indirect Command Buffers, and I can't seem to find much documentation for it online, especially in Swift. When I first attempted to do this in the project I'm working on, I found that on the M1 it would just crash when I tried setting the `MTLComputePipelineState` of the `MTLIndirectComputeCommand` using `.setComputePipelineState()`, whereas on AMD chips it would hang when trying to commit and execute the commands in the indirectCommandBuffer, and if it got through everything, it would just return memory points of 0 data.

I've created what hopefully is a minimal reproducible example to try and show what issue I'm having; it just adds two numpy arrays received from C 1000 times. Be aware this is just an example to illustrate the issue. Our goal is improve some finite difference code with Metal.

I'm currently running MacOS 12.4.

Below is the Swift function:

```
import Metal
import MetalPerformanceShaders
import Accelerate
import Foundation

@_cdecl("metalswift_add")
public func addition(array1: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>,array2: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, length: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> {

  var bFound = false
  var device : MTLDevice!
  device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
  let defaultLibrary = try! device.makeLibrary(filepath: "metal.metallib")
  let metalswift_addfunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "metalswift_add")!
  let descriptor = MTLComputePipelineDescriptor()
  descriptor.computeFunction = metalswift_addfunction
  descriptor.supportIndirectCommandBuffers = true
  let computePipelineState = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(descriptor: descriptor, options: .init(), reflection: nil)
  
  var Ref1 : UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer(array1)
  var Ref2 : UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer(array2)
  var size = length
  let SizeBuffer : UnsafeMutableRawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&size)

  let ll = MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * length

  var Buffer1:MTLBuffer! = device.makeBuffer(bytes:Ref1, length: ll, options:[])
  var Buffer2:MTLBuffer! = device.makeBuffer(bytes:Ref2, length: ll, options:[])
  var MetalBuffer:MTLBuffer! = device.makeBuffer(length: ll, options:[])
  let Size:MTLBuffer! = device.makeBuffer(bytes: SizeBuffer, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size, options: [])

  var icbDescriptor:MTLIndirectCommandBufferDescriptor = MTLIndirectCommandBufferDescriptor()
  icbDescriptor.commandTypes.insert(MTLIndirectCommandType.concurrentDispatchThreads)
  icbDescriptor.inheritBuffers = false
  icbDescriptor.inheritPipelineState = false
  icbDescriptor.maxKernelBufferBindCount = 4
  var indirectCommandBuffer = device.makeIndirectCommandBuffer(descriptor: icbDescriptor, maxCommandCount: 1)!

  let icbCommand = indirectCommandBuffer.indirectComputeCommandAt(0)
  icbCommand.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)
  icbCommand.setKernelBuffer(Buffer1, offset: 0, at: 0)
  icbCommand.setKernelBuffer(Buffer2, offset: 0, at: 1)
  icbCommand.setKernelBuffer(MetalBuffer, offset: 0, at: 2)
  icbCommand.setKernelBuffer(Size, offset: 0, at: 3)
  icbCommand.concurrentDispatchThreads(MTLSize(width:computePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1), threadsPerThreadgroup:MTLSize(width:computePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1))
  icbCommand.setBarrier()
  
  for i in 0..<1000{
  print(i)
  let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
  let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
  let computeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
  computeCommandEncoder.executeCommandsInBuffer(indirectCommandBuffer, range:0..<1)
  computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
  commandBuffer.commit()
  commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
  }
  return(MetalBuffer!.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self))
}
```

This is the Metal Function:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <metal_math>
using namespace metal;

#define size (*size_pr)
kernel void metalswift_add(const device float *Buffer1 [[ buffer(0) ]],
const device float *Buffer2[[ buffer(1) ]],
device float *MetalBuffer[[ buffer(2) ]],
const device int *size_pr[[ buffer(3) ]]) {
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        MetalBuffer[i] = Buffer1[i] + Buffer2[i];
    }
}
```

I had it working without the indirectCommandEncoders, so I believe that it's probably an issue with how I coded the indirectCommandEncoders rather than the Metal function.

If any other information is needed, let me know! Sorry if this is of low quality, this is my first question on stack.

Update: I've updated the code above with some changes that stops the code from crashing at runtime. However, I'm still running into the hanging issue on AMD Metal GPUs, and on the M1 it seems like it only goes through the Metal function once.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating the `MTLComputePipelineState` correctly. To use a pipeline state in an ICB, you need to set `supportIndirectCommandBuffers` to `true` in a pipeline state descriptor. Kinda like this:

```
let metalswift_addfunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "metalswift_add")!
let descriptor = MTLComputePipelineDescriptor()
descriptor.computeFunction = metalswift_addfunction
descriptor.supportIndirectCommandBuffers = true
let computePipelineState = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(descriptor: descriptor, options: .init(), reflection: nil)
```

With that, it should work.

By the way, I recommend running with Shader Validation. It does catch this error. You can enable it in diagnostics scheme settings or by passing an environment variable. You can find more information about shader validation by reading `man MetalValidation` in Terminal.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look; sorry for the late followup. I updated the code using the proper MTLComputePipelineState, and also using MTL_DEBUG_LAYER=1 we also caught a few other errors. I also implemented `maxKernelBufferBindCount` as that was something else we were missing.
Unfortunately, I'm still running into hanging issues on the AMD GPU, and it seems to only execute the first loop on the M1. Do you have any further suggestions that could potentially help? I edited my post. Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, I think you should be using a single queue that you create outside the loop and running the loop with autoreleasepool around the body. Have you tried running with shader validation enabled as well? Or capturing this workload with Xcode GPU Capture?